# Retrieve items by shared link (SharePoint online) using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint, office365, csom

On SharePoint Online. I've document (images) library with sub folder. These folders are shared using anonymous link.

I want to download the images that are shared using the shared link using CSOM or SP PnP

I couldn't find anything how I go about it

Comment: Please provide, in detail, what you have tried so far.

Comment: @OneNeptune I'm currently researching, so far CSOM doesn't support to this so is REST api  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/shorter-share-link-format)

So looking a way to implement this

Answer (score 0):

I found this [blog post](http://blog.larslynch.com/2019/01/3d-and-other-thumbnails-in-sharepoint.html) by Lars.

Microsoft graph API gives the desired result
To get the thumbnail URL, we need to use the Graph API.
Open the Microsoft Graph Explorer site to check your REST call syntax.

Call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/contoso.sharepoint.com:/sites/anothersitecollection:/drives to get the document libraries as drives and save the ID of the document library you need. Substitute your SharePoint tenant for "contoso" and your site collection URL component for "anothersitecollection".

Call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!aXYZmss8ZEiVokyC-JytN274MKTABCdAqaqixLW2-0JqtL9COCftQr9Ct9neeDKJ/root/children to get the documents in the document library.  Substitute your long drive ID for the example.

Call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b!aXYZmss8ZEiVokyC-JytN274MKTABCdAqaqixLW2-0JqtL9COCftQr9Ct9neeDKJ/items/01EQBDECC66F3P3O5YI5ABCIGG7O6M4Q23/thumbnails to get the thumbnail URLs.  Substitute your long document ID for the example.